# Google/Code-Prettify: Who can create syntax highlighting for solidity, serpent, and ...?

Tags: discussion, syntax-highlighting

It would be nice to use [syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184108/226837) on Ethereum Stack Exchange for our questions and answers. Stack Exchange uses [google/code-prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify).

For the development question regarding decentralized applications, the `lang-js` hint would be sufficient in most cases, however, there are more than 700 questions tagged with solidity which could benefit a prettify plugin.

**Who can create javascript code prettify syntax highlighting plugins for solidity and serpent?** `lang-sol`, `lang-se`?

It would be great if someone can step up and create pull requests for the Ethereum programming languages [directly at the google repository](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/pulls).

If we can get it included, we can request default syntax highlighing for Ethereum Stack Exchange.

See also, [Syntax highlighting language hints](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/981/226837).

Edit: If you think we need more languages added for Ethereum, comment below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a pull request for Solidity: https://github.com/google/code-prettify/pull/464

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll subscribe to track progress. Don't forget to sign the "CLA" :-)

Comment: If you don't mind I can commit _your_ contribution with my account. This way your copyright will be untouched, but we can trick that google bot :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to see JavaScript highlighting too. It doesn't seem to work on this question: [Convert input in in ether in HTML object to Wei to send to smart contract using web3](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/24060/convert-html-input-in-ether-to-wei-to-send-to-smart-contract)  Should it?

Comment: If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button.

Comment: Check the linked thread from above how to highlight JavaScript: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work

Comment: I did that, and I saw the above, so I assumed that syntax highlighting is turned off on this site. Is it? If it is supposed to work and I am just using it wrongly, I'll be glad to open a new Meta question.

Comment: Yes, I just noticed it's already there. Strange. Please create a new Meta question and tag it with `support`. Thanks!