# Bump for Google-Code-Prettify! Let's get this done!

Tags: discussion, tagging, syntax-highlighting

Follow-up of: [Google/Code-Prettify: Who can create syntax highlighting for solidity, serpent, and ...?](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/391/google-code-prettify-who-can-create-syntax-highlighting-for-solidity-serpent)

Our fellow community member *[ComandanteCheth](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/users/3991/comandantecheth)* contributed a google-code-prettify module for [solidity](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solidity), however [the pull request 464](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/pull/464) is now stuck for several month due to:

- missing Google CLA which ComandanteCheth wasn't able to sign
- unanswered review items / request for changes

Now the questions are:

1. How are we going to unstuck this process?
2. If ComandanteCheth lost track of this and does not report back: Who is willing to pick it up?
3. While we are at it, would it be worth to also include [serpent](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/serpent) and [viper](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/viper) as well?

Someone has to step up and probably create a new pull request for solidity to replace #464, sign the Google CLA and keep an eye on the progress and the reviews.

I know, all you developers out there are bored and just waiting for such a *challenging* task. :P

Comment: Related on OS.SE: https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/5661/can-i-resubmit-someone-elses-pull-request-if-he-does-not-sign-cla

Comment: Buuuuuuuump :-(