# How do I turn on python syntax highlighting?

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

Even when I specifically add a code language hint for python, code highlighting does not seem to trigger. See: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/31010/1461

I added this, plus [a newline between it and the code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132515/unable-to-force-python-syntax-highlighting):

```
<!-- language: lang-py -->
```

Maybe syntax highlighting is off site-wide? Comments on this answer came to the same conclusion about JavaScript: https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/a/515/1461

That comment suggested starting a thread about it a few months ago, but I couldn't find one.

Comment: For bonus points, I'd like to see syntax highlighting turned on automatically for anything tagged with `python`, `web3.py`, `pyethereum`, `py-evm`, etc, as described here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting

Comment: Yes, auto-highlighting would be nice and is possible. If you have the time, could you create a post suggesting a list of tags and the preferred auto-language?