# Suggestion for auto-highlighting syntax, by tag

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

[It was suggested](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/550/how-do-i-turn-on-python-syntax-highlighting?noredirect=1#comment601_550) that I make a post proposing syntax highlighting by tag.

This is based on a quick scan of [tags by popularity](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/tags?page=1&tab=popular). So the list is surely incomplete, but hopefully a good starting point.

It probably makes sense to be sparing with auto-highlighting (or at least start that way and increase it over time). For example, it's very common for people to have `go-ethereum` questions that are not about go. It seems reasonable to expect people to also tag with `golang` if they want go syntax highlighting.

I assume there is no syntax highlighting for solidity yet, so I skipped those.

- javascript

  - web3js
  - javascript
  - nodejs
  - ethereumjs
  - ethereumjs-tx
- python

  - web3.py
  - python
- java

  - web3j
  - java
- golang

  - golang
  - go
- C#

  - c#
- ruby

  - ruby